# React Native Alert Dialog background disappeared

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, alert

I'm a beginner of React Native and try to build an APP with Expo, My Alert from React Native just had problem, the dialog background disappeared and I dont know what happened cause I even dont know how to change that.

Has anyone met this problem before? Here's my package.json and the screenshot.

Screenshot

[image: 1]

```
 {
  "name": "educal-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.json",
    "lint-and-fix": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.json --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.6.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@thetalabs/theta-js": "^0.0.67",
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.1",
    "assert": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.1.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~11.2.3",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-random": "^12.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-standard-web-crypto": "^1.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "https-browserify": "^0.0.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "metro": "^0.71.0",
    "npm": "^8.16.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "path-browserify": "^0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-anchor-carousel": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-os": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-quick-base64": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-quick-crypto": "^0.4.5",
    "react-native-rsa": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-virtualized-view": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "tty-browserify": "^0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "victory-native": "^36.5.3",
    "vm-browserify": "^0.0.4",
    "web3": "^1.7.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "expo-clipboard": "~3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.6",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "node-libs-react-native": "^1.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Already solved, just clean the cache for expo APP in the phone, then everything is normal again.

Answer (score 0):

removing `<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>` from this file `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` solves the issue.

Comment: Actually I dont have android folder in my porject, but you remind me that I haved done the eject operation by mistake and remove android & ios folder, by the way, I run the APP on my old android phone and now it has the background, do you know why?

Comment: Just solved this problem with clean the expo cache, but still thanks a lot!